# 感同身受 English equivalent

Tags: translation, phrase, expressions, chengyu

As the question says, Im wondering if this 成語 has an English version.

[image]

The best I could come up with is "I feel you" in English, but I feel the Chinese version has a deeper meaning. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 感同身受 an idiomatic way to say "(empathetically) feel"

Example:

你的痛苦我**感同身受** = I (empathetically) **feel** your pain

你的失望我**感同身受** = I (empathetically) **feel** your disappointment

烏黑蘭人的痛苦波蘭人**感同身受** = The Poles (empathetically) **feel** the Ukrainians' pain

"empathetically" is redundant in English. When you say you feel someone's feeling, it is always empathetically, not actually

> "empathetically" - 感同身受地 (adv)

Example:

"I can **empathetically** feel your pain" - “我能**感同身受地**感受到你的痛苦”

"I can feel your pain" - “我能感受到你的痛苦” (it is the more natural way to speak)

"empathetically" is redundant in English

Comment: Thanks for the answer